# Writing binary data to a file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I have to admit that I am new to C++ and even new to Visual studio. I have to use Visual studio since the rest of the code is in visual studio and want to open a file and then save binary data to it. I have found some help from Visual Studio  and found a program which can send strings to a file but I want to send binary data.For this purpose I have amended the program. But the problem is that it is not performing as per expectations and sending some symbols.  I know that there are quite a lot of experts on Stack Overflow. Will any body help me in resolving my issue?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include<conio.h>



void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction);


void __cdecl _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
//void __cdecl _tmain()
{
    HANDLE hFile;
    int DataBuffer[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = 5;
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    BOOL bErrorFlag = FALSE;

    printf("\n");
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage Error:\tIncorrect number of arguments\n\n");
        _tprintf(TEXT("%s <file_name>\n"), argv[0]);
        return;
    }

    hFile = CreateFile(argv[1],                // name of the write
        GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing
        0,                      // do not share
        NULL,                   // default security
        CREATE_NEW,             // create new file only
        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
        NULL);                  // no attr. template

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("CreateFile"));
        _tprintf(TEXT("Terminal failure: Unable to open file \"%s\" for write.\n"), argv[1]);
        return;
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("Writing %d bytes to %s.\n"), dwBytesToWrite, argv[1]);

    bErrorFlag = WriteFile(
        hFile,           // open file handle
        DataBuffer,      // start of data to write
        dwBytesToWrite,  // number of bytes to write
        &dwBytesWritten, // number of bytes that were written
        NULL);            // no overlapped structure

    if (FALSE == bErrorFlag)
    {
        DisplayError(TEXT("WriteFile"));
        printf("Terminal failure: Unable to write to file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        if (dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite)
        {
            // This is an error because a synchronous write that results in
            // success (WriteFile returns TRUE) should write all data as
            // requested. This would not necessarily be the case for
            // asynchronous writes.
            printf("Error: dwBytesWritten != dwBytesToWrite\n");
        }
        else
        {
            _tprintf(TEXT("Wrote %d bytes to %s successfully.\n"), dwBytesWritten, argv[1]);
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hFile);
}


void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction)

{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf =
        (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)
        + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)
        + 40) // account for format string
        * sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (FAILED(StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error code %d as follows:\n%s"),
        lpszFunction,
        dw,
        lpMsgBuf)))
    {
        printf("FATAL ERROR: Unable to output error code.\n");
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: %s\n"), (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: Any reasons to not use `fstream` ?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ?

Comment: You are writing 5 bytes from the `int[]` DataBuffer to a file, that means your file will contain `00 00 00 01 00` or `01 00 00 00 02` depending on the endianess of your machine.

Comment: _"the problem is that it is not performing as per expectations and sending some symbols. I know that there are quite a lot of experts on Stack Overflow. Will any body help me in resolving my issue?"_ This is not an acceptable problem statement.